# c passing several arguments to threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

when i create a thread, i want to pass several arguments. 
So i define in a header file the following:

```
struct data{
  char *palabra;
  char *directorio;
  FILE *fd;
  DIR *diro;
  struct dirent *strdir;
```

};

In a .c file i do the following

```
if (pthread_create ( &thread_id[i], NULL, &hilos_hijos, ??? ) != 0){
       perror("Error al crear el hilo. \n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

How do i pass all this arguments to the threads. I though about:

1) first use malloc to allocate memory for this structure and then give each parameter a value:

```
 struct data *info
 info = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
 info->palabra = ...;
```

2) define

```
 struct data info 
 info.palabra = ... ; 
 info.directorio = ...;
```

and then, how do i access these parameters in the thread
    void thread_function ( void *arguments){
    ???
    }

thanks in advance

Comment: See answer from @SeanBright below. Also, [man](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a working (and relatively small) example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/*                                                                                                                                  
 * To compile:                                                                                                                      
 *     cc thread.c -o thread-test -lpthread                                                                                         
 */

struct info {
    char first_name[64];
    char last_name[64];
};

void *thread_worker(void *data)
{
    int i;
    struct info *info = data;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("Hello, %s %s!\n", info->first_name, info->last_name);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    struct info *info = malloc(sizeof(struct info));

    strcpy(info->first_name, "Sean");
    strcpy(info->last_name, "Bright");

    if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_worker, info)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No threads for you.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this example still work if creating multiple threads sharing the same structure or variable?  Or would that case require passing a pointer to struct info data array? Like suggested here https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use option #2.  The `data` structure could be overwritten (explicitly, for instance using the same structure to start another thread, or implicitly, for instance having it overwritten on the stack).  Use option #1.

To get at your data, at the start of your thread, do

```
struct data *info = (struct data*)arguments;
```

Then access `info` as normal.  Make sure to `free` it when the thread is done (or, as I prefer, have the caller free it after joining with the thread).

Answer (score 0):

Create a pointer to a struct like you do in the first case above:

```
//create a pointer to a struct of type data and allocate memory to it
struct data *info
info = malloc(sizeof(struct data));

//set its fields
info->palabra   = ...;
info->directoro = ...;

//call pthread_create casting the struct to a `void *`
pthread_create ( &thread_id[i], NULL, &hilos_hijos, (void *)data);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to use malloc and not define like below

```
struct data *info;
info = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

and pass the pointer of the structure in ptherad call as below

```
pthread_create ( &thread_id[i], NULL, &thread_fn, (void *)info );
```

2) you can access them in thread function as below

```
void thread_function ( void *arguments){

struct data *info = (struct data *)arguments;

info->....

}
```